# Put figure and listing side by side

Tags: graphics, listings, positioning

I'm trying to put a listing and figure side by side. I tried to follow the suggestions in this link [How to put algorithm and figure(s) side by side?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34875/how-to-put-algorithm-and-figures-side-by-side) without using caption package but the listing stays below in the figure.

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.7in]{figure}
    \caption{Figure one.}
    \label{fig:fig1}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>

 main()
 {
    printf ("Hello World!\n");
 }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Related: [Placing listing and figure side by side in memoir](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129168/placing-listing-and-figure-side-by-side-in-memoir)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: first: you *really* don't want a figure env here; remove `\begin`/`\end{figure}`; second: put `%` after the first `\end{minipage}`; third: use the `capt-of` package and use `captionof{figure}{Figure one.}`

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth}p{0.5\textwidth}}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.7in]{figure}
    \caption{Figure one.}
    \label{fig:fig1}
    \end{minipage}
    &
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>

 main()
 {
    printf ("Hello World!\n");
 }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A recommended solution by me. We can abuse `showexpl` package, that is for rendering TeX code and its output side by side, by specify the `graphic` option to prevent the `\LTXexample` or `\LTXinputExample` from rendering the code.

The following code speaks my idea clearly. Some settings are left intact for you to make the rendered code look beautiful.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{Program.cs}
using System;
namespace Delegate
{
    class Program
    {
        // start
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
                Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
        // stop
    }
}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand*{\noaccsupp}[1]{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showexpl}


\lstdefinestyle{Common}
{   
    language={[Sharp]C},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=1em,
    numberstyle=\tiny\noaccsupp,
    frame=single,
    framesep=\fboxsep,
    framerule=\fboxrule,
    rulecolor=\color{red},
    xleftmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
    xrightmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
    breaklines=true,
    breakindent=0pt,
    tabsize=2,
    columns=flexible,
    includerangemarker=false,
    rangeprefix=//\ ,
}


\lstdefinestyle{A}
{
    style=Common,
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!10},
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bf,
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    commentstyle=\color{green}
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\LTXinputExample[style=A,graphic=example-image-a]{Program.cs}
\end{document}
```

[image]